# FlutterStates/Screen becomes empty/when fixing => The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'

Tags: flutter

FlutterStates/Screen becomes empty/when fixing =>
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxkrs.png)

[Blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfRUf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `final Function currentCheckBoxState;` to `final Function(bool?) currentCheckBoxState;`

and in your void Function make your bool nullable with a ? and make a null check inside the setState with ! behind currentCheckBoxState `void checkBoxCallBack(bool? currentCheckBoxState) { setState(() {isChecked = currentCheckBoxState!; }); }`

Comment: Thank you a lot
Problem was solved successfully